# Update rows of a SQL table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with a column called 'status'. The defaut value of 'status' is 0. I want to update the value to '1' after using it.
I basically want to check if the status is 0, if it is, do an operation and then change the value to 1.

Here is the code. All works perfectly except that the value of 0 is not changed to 1.
I am a novice so maybe is a very basic mistake :(

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT number, status FROM summonerid";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $SummonerID = $row["number"];
        $status = $row["status"];

        if($status=='0'){
             $recentgames=$lol->getRecentGames($SummonerID);
             $MatchID1=$recentgames->games[0]->gameId;
             $sql = "INSERT INTO matchid (number) SELECT * FROM (SELECT '$MatchID1') AS tmp WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT number FROM matchid WHERE number = '$MatchID1') LIMIT 1;";

             $sql = "UPDATE summonerid SET status='1' WHERE status='0';"; // THIS IS THE PART THAT DOES NOT WORK WELL
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: what happens if you run the update directly from either phpmyadmin, or the mysql cli? (or whatever method you use for managing the database)

Comment: Your code is SQL injection vulnerable.

Comment: it works from phpmyadmin

Comment: Are you actually executing the $sql query after it has been set to the `UPDATE` statement? (Because I don't see the `INSERT` being executed before it is overwritten.)

Comment: You should execute a query before another query. You can't execute two queries at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.. you are not executing the sql statements

```
$sql = "SELECT number, status FROM summonerid";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

 // output data of each row
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $SummonerID = $row["number"];
    $status = $row["status"];

    if($status=='0'){
         $recentgames=$lol->getRecentGames($SummonerID);
         $MatchID1=$recentgames->games[0]->gameId;
         $sql = "INSERT INTO matchid (number) SELECT * FROM (SELECT '$MatchID1') AS tmp WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT number FROM matchid WHERE number = '$MatchID1') LIMIT 1;";

          $result1 = $conn->query($sql);
         $sql = "UPDATE summonerid SET status='1' WHERE status='0';"; 
          $result1 = $conn->query($sql); 
    }
}
}

?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! I didnt know that :) works perfectly. Seems so obvious now